# How to connect my code from VS Code to my GoDaddy domain?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-applications

I have purchased a `GoDaddy` domain and I have made a website from code through the Visual Studio Code application. I tried to link the two together so that I can have a public website with my domain name and the content from VS Code. Does anyone know how I can do this? Any suggestion in VS code ftp/sftp plugins ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is just an IDE. What you need is a hosting service/platform that will publicly serve your web application to other people. GoDaddy provides domains, and they also provide a [hosting service](https://godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting). There are lots of other hosting providers. Basically, you write your code in VS Code, upload it to the hosting platform, and connect your public domain to it so that people can access your website through the public domain.

Answer (score 2):

Download `ftp-simple` extension for VSCode and then setup the configurations file.

To setup configuration file Press `F1` -> `ftp-simple: Config - FTP connection settings`

Set up your configuration and then again press `F1` -> `ftp-simple: Remte Directory Open to Workspace`.

You can check the output is Output console by selecting `ftp-simple` in dropdown.

Comment: ftp-simple gives errors. I'm still trying to figure this out. I get the FTP Connecting... FTP close!! message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you purchased hosting service? If yes, you just need to upload your files to your root folder and make sure you point your domain to your hosting provider name server.